# mysql can't drop table, but when restart mysqld then i can drop the table

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Today I ran accross a very strange problem of mysql.

I have a database named dev in mysql, and a single table named roles in it

when I'm try to use

```
drop table roles;
```

then nothing will happend.no error or any info is echo out.

But if I restart the mysqld process.then I use `drop table roles;` then
it works. the table deleted successful.

so, what's the problem here?
Is this a bug of mysql?

---

below is the two model used to generate the table in mysql using flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role')

    default = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    permissions = db.Column(db.Integer)


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'),  default=0)
```

I can use `db.create()` to generate the table ,
but once I use `db.drop_all()`  then the roles table can't be deleted. the users table deleted successfully.

I need to restart the mysqld, then I can drop the table.

Comment: maybe recreate your database? database could be corrupted?

Comment: @Harry, I'm running unit of flask application, during each test, It's recreate all the table , and drop all the table once a test is passed. so I don't think the db can be corrupted so quick.

Comment: Check mysql server logs; does it happen with other tables?

Comment: @golimar , no only this table can't be deleted, other table can be deleted successfuly. I think I should check the mysql server logs.

Comment: When you try the drop table inspect what is going on in `show full processlist` on the MySQL server

Comment: @JoeDoherty I find the problem by show full processlist.

Comment: What is the issue in that case? Is it a dead lock?

Comment: @JoeDoherty yes it is ,it tells me '''Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction'''

Comment: @JoeDoherty You can post an answer , using show processlist and kill id works..